# How can I load several images as input data of a network using python and caffe?

Tags: python, caffe

I already have a network that receives `1 image (RGB)` as an input data and predicts the class. But now, I want to use the `ilsvrc2012` dataset as an input data. 
How can I load several images as an input data of a network using python and caffe?

For now, just for 1 input image I'm using this code:

```
# Load the image in the data layer
im = caffe.io.load_image(IMAGE_FILE)

net.blobs['data'].data[...] = transformer.preprocess('data', im)  # perform the preprocessing we've set up

# Compute forward
out = net.forward()
```

My model is defined as:

```
name: "CaffeNet"
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "Input"
  top: "data"
  input_param { shape: { dim: 1 dim: 3 dim: 227 dim: 227 } }
}
```

and my last layer is:

```
layer {
  name: "prob"
  type: "Softmax"
  bottom: "fc8"
  top: "prob"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are myriad places to get the input layers for ilsvrc2012.  I strongly recommend a spot you should already have:  **$CAFFE_ROOT/models/bvlc_alexnet/train_val.prototxt** -- the data layer at the top of that file should be what you want.

The basic "trick" is to realize that the first dimension in the **shape** attribute is the *batch size*, the number of images you will handle in each iteration.  For instance,

```
shape {
  dim: 256
  dim: 3
  dim: 227
  dim: 227
}
```

describes the same input, but accepting and processing 256 images at once.